# Why does BufWriter wrap the inner Write in an Option?

Tags: rust

In the standard library, `BufWriter` is declared as follows:

```
pub struct BufWriter<W: Write> {
    inner: Option<W>,
    buf: Vec<u8>,
    // #30888: If the inner writer panics in a call to write, we don't want to
    // write the buffered data a second time in BufWriter's destructor. This
    // flag tells the Drop impl if it should skip the flush.
    panicked: bool,
}
```

As the documentation tells us, `panicked` exists as a safety against double writes on unwind and I understand the reasoning behind it. Is there a similar reason for the inner writer being wrapped in an `Option`? The only part I find in the code where the `Option` actually gets cleared is in [`into_inner`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/f2b11f30b2946119c23594bc2b3bec3c38d3ae9a/src/libstd/io/buffered.rs#L501-L506) but I see no reason why this should not be possible with a naked value as well, as `self` as taken by value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is simple: `BufWriter` implements `Drop`, and you can't move out of a field from a type that implements `Drop`. Just before `BufWriter::into_inner` returns, `BufWriter::drop` is called, because the `BufWriter` is moved into the function's `self` parameter, then falls out of scope – this is standard RAII.

If you were able to move out of a field, then what happens with the destructor? Either it wouldn't be called at all, which would be surprising, or it would be called with some fields containing invalid values, which could violate memory safety.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. Could you use the Option to protect against the panic as well then? I.e. instead of `self.panicked = true`, temporarily `take` the inner writer and give it back afterwards.

Comment: @HeroicKatora I think so, but it might be slightly more costly because it would involve making two (shallow) copies of `W` (whose size we have no idea of). The `panicked` field, on the other hand, is one byte long, so it's a known, small, fixed cost.

Comment: Related: [RFC 2061: Destructure drop structs](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2061) was closed as `postponed` some days ago.

Comment: [PR #36336](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/36336) is also related.